# Character encoding mismatch on certain web pages

Tags: firefox, browser, website, character-encoding

I use recent release of Firefox for viewing web pages. When I visit some sites – [this one](http://anthropology.ua.edu/cultures/cultures.php?culture=Postmodernism%20and%20Its%20Critics) and [this](http://www.depauw.edu/sfs/backissues/16/williams16art.htm) – Firefox displays a diamond shaped character in the web page in places where punctation characters should appear.

I am aware that it is a character encoding mismatch issue. So, is there any way – either by using Firebug or any other plugin – to get the pages diplayed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The diamond shaped character is U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, and browsers may display it to indicate character-level data error (bytes that do not represent any character in the currently applied character encoding).

Your first case is a page declared to be UTF-8 encoded, but it is in fact windows-1252 encoded. If you manually tell Firefox to apply that encoding (View > Encoding, West European (Windows), or something like that), you will see the characters as intended, as “smart quotes.” On the authoring side, the issue should be fixed e.g. by changing the `meta` tag to declare windows-1252 and not utf-8.

The second case is similar and can be fixed similarly in a browser; in this case, the page contains em dashes (—) in windows-1252 encoding. On the authoring side, this could be more difficult, since here the encoding is declared in HTTP headers and cannot be overridden in the document itself; web server admin action might be needed.